# Form Validation using onclick() event

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

So I'm having some issues getting my validation which resides in my php action script.

I have the following form:

```
<form action="contact.php" method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contact_form" name="contact_form">

<div class="div_input"><input name="name" type="text" value="Name: " class="input4" /></div>
<div class="div_input"><input name="phone" type="text" value="Phone: " class="input4" /></div>
<div class="div_input"><input name="email" type="text" value="E-mail: " class="input4" /></div>
<textarea name="message" cols="0" rows="0" class="textarea2" >Message: </textarea>
```

Then I am submitting using the onclick() method. This is where my issue is arising I believe.

```
<div class="link4"><span><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contact_form').submit()">send</a></span></div>

<div class="link4"><span><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contact_form').reset()">clear</a></span></div>
</form>
```

And my script...

```
<?php
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'test@test.com';
$name = $phone = $email = $message ='';
$nameError = $emailError =$phoneError = $messageError = '';

if(empty($_POST['name']))
{$nameError='Name is required!';}
else
{
    $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
    {
        $nameError='Only letters and white space allowed';
    }
}

if(empty($_POST['email']))
{$emailError='Email is required!';}
else
{
    $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
    //check to make sure is a valid email format
    if(!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
    {
        $emailError = "Invalid email format!";
    }
}

if(empty($_POST['phone']))
{
    'Phone number is required';
}
else
{
    $phone = test_input($_POST['phone']);
    //Allow only digits in the phone number
    if(!preg_match("/^[\d\-]+$/",$phone));
    {
        $phoneError = 'Phone must be only numbers and dashes';
    }
}

if (empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $messageError = 'Message is required!';
}
else
{
    $message = test_input($_POST['message']);
}

function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}


$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
"Email: $email\n Phone Number: $phone\n Message \n $message";
$headers = "From: $email \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
//header('Location: index-5.html');
?>
```

When I test this, no validation runs at all. I can click send with the form empty and no errors appear.

I've seen a couple people having issues with the javascript onclick function and validation in their php script. Could this be it? Or am I missing something in my script or form? I'm thinking maybe I need to add some javascript after the submit() method.

What do you all think?

Comment: try to `print_r($_POST);` in the starting line of php code

Comment: Your email regex is bad. Your way of emulating HTML input buttons (submit/reset) is also bad. You shouldn't write code like this.

Comment: Thanks @RainFromHeaven, I'll look into the regex. Can you elaborate on the proper way I should be doing the input buttons and what you mean for those of us that have a thick head like me?

Comment: @Braden buttons should be `<button>` or `<input type=button>` or `<input type=submit>`, not `<a>`.

Comment: As @Pointy pointed out (pun intended), the functionality is built right into HTML - there's no reason to reinvent the wheel. As for the regexes, a regex to validate an email address is probably one of the hardest to write and most commonly needed out there.

Comment: @RainFromHeaven thanks, I used the submit method I did because of CSS issues I was having using <input type=submit>. I'll work on fixing that. As for the regex for email, I worked on it last night and got something that should handle most any addresses I will get submitted. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Braden consider `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Comment: Thanks @RainFromHeaven and (webinista) I'd upvote some of your suggestions as they've been very helpful but I'm one rep away from the minimum to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your PHP script is sending the message regardless of whether or not there's an error.

Try checking whether `$nameError`, `$emailError`,`$phoneError`, and `$messageError` are all empty strings before submitting.

Other suggested improvements:

1. Read up on [PHP's filter functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) and use them instead of your regular expressions.
2. Take advantage of HTML5 validation in browsers that support it by adding `required` to all of your input fields.
3. Use `<input type="submit" value="send">` and `<input type="reset" value="clear">` instead of onclick. They're a little bit harder to style with CSS, but it's better for accessibility and works even when JavaScript doesn't.

Comment: Okay that makes sense to stop it from sending if errors. Something like this should work.
    if(empty($error1) || empty(error2) || empty(error3)
    {
    do mail;
    }
    else 
    {error message;}

Comment: This will prevent the form from being sent with a generic error, but doesn't explain why my if/else for each field aren't doing the validation. Do I need to somehow echo them in the form itself for those errors to show up?

Comment: Yes. One way to do this -- and it's a bit too complicated to explain in the comments -- is to use sessions. Save the error messages to a session and redirect to the form with the messages printed.

Comment: thanks @webinista I'll research into sessions. Also saw your other suggestions edit just now, number 3 and CSS is exactly why I did it the way I did. I couldn't get the styling right using <inputs>.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see is

```
if(empty($_POST['phone']))
{ 
    'Phone number is required';
}
```

should be

```
if(empty($_POST['phone']))
{ 
    $phoneError = 'Phone number is required';
}
```